# Electron app: "SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly"

Tags: debian, terminal, application, atom-editor

I had the same issue recently after attempting to start another Electron-based app (`particl-desktop`), and I was able to manually fix it by running:

```
sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

This enabled me to successfully start the package mentioned above. However, before doing the same thing again, I want to know *why* this is happening and whether there is a more permanent fix in case this *keeps* happening.

I've read that alternatively these apps can be launched with the `--no-sandbox` flag. But is it safe to do this?

## Distribution

Debian 10 (Buster)

## Issue

```
atom &
/usr/bin/atom: line 190: 27367 Trace/breakpoint trap   nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[27367:0520/072821.694231:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/share/atom/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

## Further information

```
uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
journalctl
May 20 07:28:21 debian kernel: traps: atom[27367] trap int3 ip:560ceaee7627 sp:7ffdfd684ad0 error:0 in atom[560ce8fc3000+5024000]
```

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep atom
ii  atom                                   1.47.0                               amd64        A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem when I updated to version 1.47.0. As you mentioned you could remove sandboxing, but a better fix for the time being would be to just downgrade to the previous version.

This shows all of the versions you can downgrade to (you should probably pick v1.46.0):

```
sudo apt-cache policy atom
```

After just run:

```
sudo apt install atom=1.46.0
```

Btw this assumes that you have atom repo in you sources.list.d directory. You can check with:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls
```

You should then see atom.list. If you don't, see [installing atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/)

Comment: For the time being (and until someone suggests something better), I've been manually `chown`ing and `chmod`ing as outlined at the top of the post, which seems to work fine and doesn't seem to have any side effects that I can detect.